# randomForest Error: NA not permitted in predictors (but no NAs in data)

Tags: r, machine-learning, bioinformatics, random-forest, na

So I am attempting to run the 'genie3' algorithm (ref: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/vhuynht/software.html) in R which uses the 'randomForest' method.

I am running into the following Error:

```
> weight.matrix<-get.weight.matrix(tmpLog2FC, input.idx=1:4551)
Starting RF computations with 1000 trees/target gene,
and 67 candidate input genes/tree node
Computing gene 1/11805
Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtry, ntree = nb.trees, importance = TRUE,  : 
NA not permitted in predictors
```

So I checked if NAs are present in my data, and there are none:

```
> NAs<-sapply(tmpLog2FC, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
> length(which(NAs!=0))
[1] 0
```

I then tried editing the specific 'get.weight.matrix()' function to omit NAs (just in case) by changing this line:

```
rf <- randomForest(x, y, mtry=mtry, ntree=nb.trees, importance=TRUE, ...)
```

To:

```
rf <- randomForest(x, y, mtry=mtry, ntree=nb.trees, importance=TRUE, na.action=na.omit)
```

I then sourced the code, and double checked that it incorporated the changes by calling it on its own (and displaying the actual script):

```
    }
    target.gene.name <- gene.names[target.gene.idx]
    # remove target gene from input genes
    these.input.gene.names <- setdiff(input.gene.names, target.gene.name)
    x <- expr.matrix[,these.input.gene.names]
    y <- expr.matrix[,target.gene.name]
    rf <- randomForest(x, y, mtry=mtry, ntree=nb.trees, importance=TRUE, na.action=na.omit)
```

However when attempting to re-run, I get the same error:

```
Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtry, ntree = nb.trees, importance = TRUE,  : 
NA not permitted in predictors
```

Has anyone encountered anything similar to this? Any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT: As suggested, I re-ran with debug:

```
> weight.matrix<-get.weight.matrix(tmpLog2FC, input.idx=1:4551)
Starting RF computations with 1000 trees/target gene,
and 67 candidate input genes/tree node
Computing gene 1/11805
Error in randomForest.default(x, y, mtry = mtry, ntree = nb.trees, importance = TRUE,  : 
NA not permitted in predictors
Called from: randomForest(x, y, mtry = mtry, ntree = nb.trees, importance = TRUE, 
na.action = na.omit)
Browse[1]> 
>
```

The debug shows that the line that I suspected is throwing the error, but it displays it in the edited form with 'na.action=na.omit'. I am even more confused. How can a dataset that has no NAs, run with a code that allows for NAs to be omitted, display this error?

Comment: One more thing to try: use `debug()` to step through the function and check for NAs at various points along the way, right up to right before the randomForest call. You may spot some NAs creeping in that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my post with the debug ran.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Somewhere, somehow, NAs are being introduced. The first step to successfully debugging something is to start believing the error message. We just haven't looked hard enough for where that is happening. I was suggesting that you step through `get.weight.matrix` one line at a time, testing `expr.matrix` for NAs multiple times as you go. Additionally you'll want to check `x` right before the `randomForest` call.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Thats basically what I have been doing and I continuously get stuck on the same line. I will continue on this path until someone hopefully shines more light on this issue. Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: I would love to help more, but it will be difficult for anyone to help without a reproducible example. My only other suggestion is that one way this could happen is if you were passing a data frame, rather than a matrix, and you ended up with some mixed types in columns after it was transposed.

Comment: I understand completely. I am frustrated with my own inability to debug. The file is in the correct format: 
> str(tmpLog2FC)
 num [1:11805, 1:8] 0.384 -0.345 0.47 Inf 0.408 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2

Comment: Oho! What is that I spy! An `Inf`! See...you'd totally be able to see the consequences of that with the debugging process I described. The function transposes the matrix, and then scales the columns. But the `Inf` will cause the mean to be `Inf` and the sd to be `NaN`. Divide the two and you'll get an NA. That means that further on the in the function `expr.matrix` _does_ contain NAs, just as R is telling you.

Comment: (or rather, it gives you `NaN`, and `is.na(NaN)` returns TRUE, which is sort of odd, until you think about it a bit)

Comment: Nice catch! So, in following (pardon my R ignorance here) but is it possible to add a 'na.omit' parameter (or something equivalent) to that 'apply' function: expr.matrix <- apply(expr.matrix, 2, function(x) { (x - mean(x)) / sd(x) } ) ?

Comment: Both `mean` and `sd` have a `na.rm` argument that will drop `NA`s, but that won't do anything with `Inf`. And even if you drop the `Inf`s from the `mean` and `sd` calculations, the `Inf` is still included in the arithmetic in the original vector and will yield another `Inf`, the effect of which may still be bad. You may be better off removing the cases with the `Inf` up front (`is.finite`), or better yet, investigate why they are there in the first place and whether it makes sense to use this procedure on data that had you dividing by zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very appreciative of your assistance. I will do what I can to relieve the data of Inf values as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to find out the list of rows in which if any predictor will have no value it will be displayed.

data[!complete.cases(data),]

Check that rows carefully, like in my case the rows having no value **",,,,,,,,,"** (in my file columns predictor variables were comma separated) were showed as NA at the time of RF run.

You can either delete that rows.

Thanks